# Is custom membership provider the thing that really worth to follow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

After long tries to get answer to my question "Should I write custom MembershipProvider implementation or make my own custom system?" on SO I decided that it's not so bad to go MembershipProvider's way and start writing my membership provider. But at the time I feel some trouble.

For instance, in my system there's no user names. The emails are user names. So the CreateUser method should look like this:

```
public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
{
    bool userExists = GetUser(email);
    if (userExists) {
        status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail;
        return null;
    }
    bool? tryExists = regTryExists(email);
    if (tryExists.HasValue && tryExists.Value && !userExists)
    {
        UserRepository.CreateUser(email, password);
        status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
        return GetUser(email);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Also, thus I don't need `GetUserNameByEmail`,`FindUsersByName` methods:

```
public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
{
    return email;
}  

public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

So here I don't need `username, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer, isApproved` arguments.

Also, in my system there is no user questions, so I don't need such methods as

```
public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
{
    return false;
}
public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And this is just a part of waste and cumbersome membership system. It's not so realiable as I want.

So the question is Is it really worth to go with MembershipProvider? Could you please bring me over? Is there good advantages for MembershipSystem that makes it really value system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the MembershipProvider essentially boils down to the "build or buy" decision any developer (or dev mgr) has to make: build it from scratch, or buy off-the-shelf (or in this case, use a pre-existing tool).

With that in mind... admittedly, the MembershipProvider isn't perfect - it's a bit clunky, and probably has too much (or too little) of what you'll need - but it's 85% of the way there for most implementations. And as alluded to by others, building your own authentication system from scratch just isn't worth the time or effort. **This is a solved problem**; use your development energy to solve more urgent and relevant business problems, not re-inventing the wheel!

Remember this axiom: unless you can gain a direct competitive advantage from developing something from scratch, you are (usually) better off using an existing tool for the job (buy, don't build).

Comment: But if I put additional efforts on going with cumbersome tool isn't this waste if 'development energy'?

Comment: Putting on my dev-mgr hat, let's determine the ROI of this build-or-buy scenario. Build: weeks (at **least**) of building your own authentication provider (db design, CRUD sprocs (there are 25 of them!), testing, etc.). "Buy" (i.e., use existing MembershipProvider): suffer a few days of being annoyed and having to re-jigger some sprocs/methods, then get on with your life. 

Unless you want to build a whole new asp.net authentication system, and post it on GitHub and get all the glory, don't bother!

Comment: Thanks for your explanations! Very good thoughts. Seems like you break all my doubts! Btw what is the 25 procs of CRUD?

Comment: Sprocs is my shorthand for stored procedures (database), and CRUD is short for Create/Retrieve/Update/Delete. So, there are 25 database stored procedures that handle managing the data for the aspnet_MembershipProvider solution. From your MembershipProvider database, run this query: SELECT * FROM sys.procedures

Answer (score 1):

Some advantages of the ASP.NET membership provider API:

- You don't have to reinvent the wheel. New comers on your project will be familiar with a well-known API.
- There are already implementations (SQL Server, Active Directory mostly) available you can re-use or start from.
- It's visually integrated with ASP.NET (Login Controls, etc.)
- You can use the built-in ASP.NET administration tool to create users & roles (it's in fact a good way to check your provider works fine, as it should work with the tool)
- It can be integrated with  the .NET (not only ASP.NET) Identity / Principal classes, and can be used to support the PermissionAttribute system (with the associated Role Provider). Although it technically lives in System.Web.dll, you can in fact use it in non-web systems.
- One last thing but quite interesting: you can also use ASP.NET membership providers in [WCF services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx)

Comment: Existing implementations also not so reliable and cumbersome. And very bound to DB scheme. So you can't change db scheme at all. Third item isn't applicable for MVC architecture.

Comment: I don't agree on the 'reliable' term. They are quite reliable and exist for more than 6 years, also used by a lot of people. Are they 'cumbersome'? I suppose it's more a matter of opinion :-) You'right on the fact they are not really designed to be changed, you'll have to use them or rewrite your own.

Answer (score 0):

Well MembershipProvider is indeed useful. The complete ASP.Net security infrastructure is build around it. Lot of the control can directly interact with this infrastructure such as Login, LoginStatus. So it does have it's advantage. 
But it also has it's fair share of problem due to its fat interface. It's breaking the interface segregation principle and hence is a little cumbersome to use. I believe the advantages outweigh the penalty we pay here. So as long there are simple workarounds there are no harms using it. 
Building your own security infrastructure is not a trivial task either.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the default `MembershipProvider` does everything you need it to do.
Therefore I would definitely recommend creating a `UserBusiness`class that wraps the `MembershipProvider` and only exposes the features you use.

This makes it easy to use the great features of the `MembershipProvider` but also simplifies the interface for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I used custom provider first but now switched out completely.

I kept just a principle where things like when to lock user, how to hash password, etc

I was fine with custom provider until I needed multi-tenant support with different databases. And last drop was my attempt to unit test WCF service that used membership provider. Now I have my MembershipService and life is good. I still have data structure almost identical to original, but in .NET I use my code